# split characters and numbers in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a column in my table like this,

```
students
--------
abc23
def1
xyz567
......
```

and so on. Now i need output like only names
Need output as

```
students
--------
abc
def
xyz
```

How can i get this in mysql. Thanks advance.

Comment: try to use substr(students,1,3)

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention. the length of characters are different. i forgot to notify that. may be 5 or more than

Comment: What is the format of value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with [string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) ans some [`CAST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) magic:

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTR(
    name, 
    1, 
    CHAR_LENGTH(@name) - CHAR_LENGTH(
      IF(
        @c:=CAST(REVERSE(name) AS UNSIGNED),
        @c,
        ''
      )
    )
  ) 
FROM 
  students
```

for example:

```
SET @name:='abc12345';

mysql> SELECT SUBSTR(@name, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(@name) - CHAR_LENGTH(IF(@c:=CAST(REVERSE(@name) AS UNSIGNED), @c, ''))) AS name;
+------+
| name |
+------+
| abc  |
+------+
```

Comment: In case if the column value like this means 'welcome' no numeric value  then it returns 'welcom' only. it trimmed the last character.

Comment: Well, it's not a problem. I've added `IF` check

Comment: `'abc10'` reversed -> `'01abc'` casted -> `1` char_length -> `1`. but expect 2. do we have a solution?